# Cypress mat-select select command failing

Tags: material-ui, cypress

Trying to test a select control with Cypress. I found the `.select(option)` command which seems pretty straight-forward, but cannot get it to work

This is my form:

```js
<form>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Food ingredients</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

This is my test:

```js
cy.get('mat-select').click()
  .select('Cauliflower')
```

but it throws the error "cy.select() can only be called on a `<select>`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular mat-select isn't a normal `<select>` element, you can't use the `.select()` command.

Use `.click()` instead

```js
cy.get('mat-select').click()
cy.contains('mat-option', 'Cauliflower').click()
```

This is the runtime HTML

```html
<div class="mat-select-panel-wrap">
  <div role="listbox">
    <mat-option role="option">
      <span class="mat-option-text"> Cabbage </span>
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option role="option">
      <span class="mat-option-text"> Cauliflower </span>
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option role="option">
      <span class="mat-option-text"> Capsicum </span>
    </mat-option>
  </div>
</div>
```